# javascript sets - adding value to array in object inside a set

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object, discord.js

I'm trying to make an array of sets to make something like this

```
{
    'user1': ["value#1", "value#2",..."value#N"],
    'user2': ["value#2",..."value#N"],
    'userN': [..."value#N"]
}
```

and then remove the `value#x` after 5 seconds (for example).

here is my code:

```
var myset = new Set();
var ran = myset[USERID] = commandNumber;

//i'm trying to make "if myset contains userNumber AND commandName" return, 
//if its not, run someFunction() and continue
if (myset.has(ran)) return;
someFunction();

myset.add(ran);
setTimeout(() => {
  myset.delete(ran);
}, 5000);
```

instead of getting output like the first code, i get this output instead

```
Set { 'command1', 'command2',
'USER1': 'command3',
'USER2': 'command4'
'USERN': 'commandN'
}
```

Feel free to comment if you have a question, so sorry if my question is hard to understand

Comment: `myset[USERID]` really? it adds a new property to a set instance, but no feature of a set could be used for it.

Comment: Click `<>` and produce a [mcve]

Comment: And okay @mplungjan , gonna delete this and post a new one.
or edit this one

Comment: Why not create a snippet? Your code could show what it did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Set for this purpose is not necessary but I did a small POC that could help you to implement the solution you need:

```
'use strict';

const mySet = new Set();
const mySetMetadata = {};

const removeFromSet = (userKey, commandName) => {
  const commands = mySetMetadata[userKey] || [];
  if (commands.includes(commandName)) {
    mySetMetadata[userKey] = commands.filter(c => c !== commandName);

    if (mySetMetadata[userKey].length === 0) {
      mySet.delete(userKey);
      mySetMetadata[userKey] = undefined;
    }
  }
};

/**
 * Add relation between an userKey and a command
 * @param {String} userKey
 * @param {Array} commands Array of commands
 */
const addToSet = (userkey, commands) => {
  mySet.add(userkey);

  if (typeof mySetMetadata[userkey] === 'undefined') {
    mySetMetadata[userkey] = commands;
  } else {
    mySetMetadata[userKey] = [...mySetMetadata[userKey], ...commands]
  }  
}

// Populate with demo data
addToSet('user1', ['value#1', 'value#2', 'value#N']);
addToSet('user2', ['value#2', 'value#N']);
addToSet('user3', ['value#N']);

// Set up a timeout for a given user + key
setTimeout(() => {
  removeFromSet('user1', 'value#2');
}, 5000);
```

Comment: I, somehow solved this, but this one looks similar to mine and even cleaner. Thank you very much! gonna try this :)